# Set parameter when defining dependencies in DAG

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag that has a structure like:

```
def do_thing(**kwargs):
   lib.do_thing(kwargs['thing_type'])

do_thing_type_a = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "do_thing_type_a",
        python_callable = do_thing,
        op_kwargs = {"thing_type": "A"}
    )

do_thing_type_b = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "do_thing_type_b",
        python_callable = do_thing,
        op_kwargs = {"thing_type": "B"}
    )

do_thing_type_a
do_thing_type_b
```

The real DAG is more complex and has other functions that are downstream of `do_thing_type_a` and `do_thing_type_b` but this I think demonstrates the particular question.

Essentially in the same DAG I'd like to execute the same function twice but with a different value for the parameter. The simple way as I've done in this example is to create two tasks - one for each type - and run them both but this feels like it violates basic DRY principles and affects maintainability as if I want to make a change to the task I'll have to make the change in both versions of the task.

Ideally I would like to be able to define one task such as `do_thing_type` and then pass a parameter like 'A' or 'B' when creating the dependencies, but I don't know if there's anyway to do this.

What is the best approach for this in Airflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a loop:

```
def do_thing(**kwargs):
   lib.do_thing(kwargs['thing_type'])

items_dict = {"a": "A", "b": "B"}

for key, val in items_dict.items():
    do_thing_type_a = PythonOperator(
            task_id = f"do_thing_type_{key}",
            python_callable = do_thing,
            op_kwargs = {"thing_type": val}
        )
```